# How can I flexibly parse dates?

Tags: java

The built-in java parsers seem relatively rigid.  Is there another library (or another class in the standard library) I can look at which parses dates in any format?

I realize there are corner cases like 4/5/2010 I'd need a format locale for, but I'm currently not even able to handle times both with and without seconds.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, you'll have to tell Java what an acceptable date looks like. As you've mentioned, there are many formats that dates can present themselves in. Check out [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), from the JDK. You can come up with just about any format you need with that. As for the case of "it has to be one of these six formats", I've avoided trying to be too clever with the format string and just tried them all one by one until one worked. It might not be the prettiest solution, but it works when there are a few different known formats.

Answer (score 1):

You would do worse than to use [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net)'s formatting capabilities. There's a [user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) that will get you started. Leave a comment if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes, Joda-Time provides many formatters to parse a string into a date-time. Joda-Time also offers way to build your own formatters. But no magic; your users must type in something that your code is expecting. Alternatively, add a date picker to your app, a GUI device to let them indicate a date-time value by mouse rather than by typing.

Comment: Artificial intelligence is not at the stage yet where a it can distinguish whether 12/04/1979 is in April or in December.